# How to download a PDF file with selenium python webdriver?

Tags: python, pdf, selenium-chromedriver

Website: http://mbct.com/wp-content/uploads/Eisendrath-Jan-2016.pdf

Error: unable to locate the element

Maybe this is because the download icon will disappear when I don't do something?

This is my code:

```
# coding=utf-8
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
import time
import os
site = 'http://mbct.com/wp-content/uploads/Eisendrath-Jan-2016.pdf'
br = webdriver.Chrome()
br.get(site)
br.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="icon"]').click()
```

Comment: You appear to be trying to find an XML element in a PDF. PDF, unlike HTML, does not overlap with XML. The download icon that shows up if you visit a PDF in your browser is not a part of the webpage.

Comment: If your goal, as it seems, is to download the PDF... you can do that by just downloading the URL by whatever means you like - you shouldn't need to use a webdriver (or any Python at all) for that, just load it with curl in a shell script. If you do want to use Python for whatever reason, `urllib.request` (Python 3) or `urllib2` (Python 2) can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Transferred from comment to answer:

You appear to be trying to find an XML element in a PDF. PDF, unlike HTML, does not overlap with XML, so that's not going to work.

The download icon that shows up if you visit a PDF in your browser is not a part of the webpage, so even if a PDF was XML, that wouldn't work. Also, there's a decent chance that there's more than one icon, in which case you'd probably be clicking on the wrong thing, and it might not be clickable (if you were using this for some non-PDF thing with a download button on the actual webpage).

To download a PDF from a website... you shouldn't need to use a webdriver (or any Python at all). Just load it with curl in a shell script, if you're on UNIX. There's probably a simple Windows equivalent but I don't know it. If you do want to use Python for whatever reason, `urllib.request` (Python 3) or `urllib2` (Python 2) can do it.

Or, if it really is just that website, you don't need to run an automatic program at all - just right-click the link and choose "Save link as..." or equivalent in most browsers.